# is there any api to make a shortcut of chrome standalone app to a desktop

Tags: google-chrome-app

normally what happens when you install an app is that it creates a shortcut from where you can launch it on desktop or start menu. However, chrome apps for now are places in chrome app launcher that is packed with all other chrome apps. It's all good and fine. But is there a way to place my app on desktop with user's consent if need be.

There is a way to do it manually. Like if user right clicks on the app in chrome app launcher and click create shortcut which has checkboxes showing places where shortcuts are going to be created ex: desktop, startmenu...

Without a icon of your app on desktop it still doesn't feel like a standalone app.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [chrome.management.createAppShortcut](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-createAppShortcut) API that is added recently. Now it's only available on the dev channel:

```
chrome.management.createAppShortcut("app_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. Users can also drag their app from the app launcher to the desktop to create a shortcut.

An API to prompt the user for this isn't something we're likely to support. Personally I think users would find it annoying, as it is simple and easy to create shortcuts where they want.

If you disagree please file a feature request at http://crbug.com. It would be there is some action we could take, e.g. educate users better that they can create shortcuts, but crbug.com is a better place to discuss.

Comment: even i had hard time finding that little white square in my quick launch. Because i am just not used to it. Most of the time i just use start menu which shows recent program. Do apps show up there if they are opened regularly...Like if i open photoshop it will be at top in start menu will the app the launched from chrome app launcher show up there.

Comment: I'm not sure if things show up in the quick launch. We do create things in the start menu so they could / should ... but I'm not sure if they do. It probably depends on how you start the app.

Comment: It's important to have an api to create desktop launchers.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985312/google-chrome-app-easy-install-and-launch-for-the-user

Comment: Exactly...its annoying to open that tiny app launcher..when you can just make your app show up in start menu or straight at desktop to double click etc.