# Can I add a website shortcut to the Home Screen from a Angular web app using only press a button without PWA

Tags: javascript, html, angular, browser, homescreen

I have a web application made in Angular and I would like to know if there is a way (without using PWA) in which the user presses a button and this adds a shortcut to his home page, something similar to what is offered by browsers

[image: Example]

Comment: I don't think so. Out of curiosity: what's wrong with the PWA method?

Comment: You looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398327/is-there-any-api-to-make-a-shortcut-of-chrome-standalone-app-to-a-desktop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger the simple "Add to home screen" feature (the one without service worker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753356/how-to-trigger-the-simple-add-to-home-screen-feature-the-one-without-service)